# How to create a table with consecutive numbers

Tags: mysql

I need a helper table with only one int(11) column, that contains a row for each consecutive number from 1 to a given max. Can this be done with pure SQL?

*Example:*

```
INSERT INTO `helper`('itnum') VALUES (1),(2),(3),...(999999),(1000000);
```

I need a statement like this, but without explicitly listing all the entries to be made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
DELIMITER |
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insert_helper_records |
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_helper_records(a_max INTEGER)
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_iteration INTEGER;
    SET v_iteration := 1;
    insert_loop: LOOP
        INSERT INTO helper(itnum) VALUES (v_iteration);
        SET v_iteration := v_iteration + 1;
        IF v_iteration = a_max THEN
            LEAVE insert_loop;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END |
DELIMITER ;
```

Then call it however you want like:

```
SELECT insert_helper_records(999999) FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: What is the advantage of `SELECT insert_helper_records(999999) FROM DUAL` over `CALL insert_helper_records(999999)`?

Comment: No real advantage to one over another, just preference.

Answer (score 1):

i think to do this, you have to execute your insert inside a loop in your SGBD procedure, or outside (php script, ...).